# Character String 2D array

Tags: c, arrays

A section of code to declare a character array with up to 16 values and 10 names, a statement to read in the character array as a character string, then print them out as a string using the %s format character. Enter a name from the keyboard.

```
int i;

char name[10][16];

for(i=0; i<10; i++){
   scanf("%s", name[i]);
}

for(i=0; i<10; i++){
   printf("%s", name[i]);
}
```

After I enter names by keyboard, ctrl+d does't shows up anything.

Ex enter:

linus

chenxi

yangzi

ctrl+d

Comment: Show the full code. And define "never works". And remove the irrelevant tags.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, first time post something.

Comment: *Code never works*. It did work as you wanted it to in my system.

Comment: This doesn't look like C# to me...

Comment: And show the names exactly as you entered them. Why do you expect `Ctrl+D` to show anything? The 10 names are printed after entering 10 names.

Comment: Well if you are programming in c# this definitely won't work, as you are using c/c++ syntax.

Comment: scanf and printf are standard c language and not part of c#.

Comment: I said it wrong, it's c code not c#. I thought c and c# are the same, sorry for that.

Comment: `Ctrl+D` followed by `Enter`, and please act on the second comment: from @usr.

Comment: @WeatherVane how I make it works if I only want 5 names without change array?

Comment: Check return value of `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

As written, your code tries to read 10 names no matter what.

To exit on end-of-file (e.g. by entering control-D ENTER in some operating systems), you need to check for end-of-file in the loop that reads the data.  In that case, you'll also need to remember how many values you've read, and only print that number.  (If you don't, it'll seem to work but only because the array is initialized to zero.  If you used the same array again later, you could get garbled results.)

See the manual page for scanf and look for EOF.

You might also want to print each name with a newline at the end.